# If you draw two cards in consecutively in a standard deck of 52 cards, what is the probability of getting black on the second draw?

Tags: probability

This is my thought process:

$P(2^{nd}\ \text{black}) = P(2^{nd}\ \text{black} \mid 1^{st}\ \text{red}) P(1^{st}\ \text{red}) + P(2^{nd}\ \text{black} \mid 1^{st}\ \text{black}) P(1^{st} \ \text{black}) $

$\frac{26}{51}*\frac{26}{52} + \frac{25}{51}*\frac{26}{52} = \frac{1}{2} $

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is correct.

Sanity check: By symmetry, the likelihood to get a black is equal to the probability og getting a red at any draw position.

Comment: What do you mean by "by symmetry"?

Comment: propotion of black and red are equal. It is like two equally competent player are playing a fair game, they are equally likely to win the game.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are right.

The intuition behind why your answer is symmetrically ${1\over 2}$ is that **if you first draw a card and close your eyes over its color (e.g. throw it away), you are in a full ambiguity or lack of information about the color of the second one. Hence the probability is the same**.

This is also the same case for any number of color types and drawing the second card.

Answer (score 2):

The "hard way":

To get a black card on the second draw you must get either "red, black" or "black, black".

1) "red, black":  There are 52 cards in the deck, 26 or them red.  The probability the first card drawn is red is 26/52= 1/2.  Given that, there are now 51 cards in the deck, 26 of them black.  The probability the second card drawn is black is 26/51.  The probability of "red, black" is (1/2)(26/51)= 13/51.

2) "black, black:  There are 52 cards in the deck, 26 or them black.  The probability the first card drawn is red is 26/52= 1/2.  Given that, there are now 51 cards in the deck, 25 of them black.  The probability the second card drawn is black is 25/51.  The probability of "red, black" is (1/2)(25/51)= 25/102.

The probability of either "red, black" or "black, black", since those are mutually exclusive, is 13/51+ 25/102= 26/102+ 25/102= 51/102= 1/2!

Answer (score 1):

You are correct... unless the colour of the first card is known, in which case it would be either:

$\dfrac{25}{51}$ if the first card was black, or
$\dfrac{26}{51}$ if the first card was red